# Toolbar of digital signatures

Tags: buttons, color, toolbar, viewer

Where I work, we have one of our systems in a web viewer for PDF files signed with the extension ". P7s."

We are doing a toolbar similar to the adobe reader (picture below). The panel is also of signatures on the left.

[image: Toolbar signatures adobe reader]

It's a good idea to make the interface similar to the PDF viewer Adobe Reader since many Users are already used to the interface, or would you rather do something different in matters of placement of buttons and colors?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know for a fact that your users are familiar with the Adobe style - then use it. That knowledge can be acquired from doing surveys on a representative selection of your users. If not, feel free to make improvements of the original design.

Good luck!